# Access properties of a file at FTP server

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, batch-file

I want to access properties of a file named AH_store_20120117_00432.csv at ftp server with url ftp.mysite.com. Properties such as last modified date/time,size, etc.

I am accessing ftp server from batch file as follows:

```
@echo off
>ftp2.txt Echo open _ftp.mysite.com
>>ftp2.txt Echo username
>>ftp2.txt Echo password
>>ftp2.txt Echo cd dir1\dir2
>>ftp2.txt Echo quit
ftp -s:ftp2.txt
```

The file is present in dir2.
FTP site can be accessed from above code, but not the file properties.

Kindly help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

command `dir` gets some info about files
For your batch file:

```
@echo off
>ftp2.txt Echo open _ftp.mysite.com
>>ftp2.txt Echo username
>>ftp2.txt Echo password
>>ftp2.txt Echo cd dir1\dir2
>>ftp2.txt Echo dir
>>ftp2.txt Echo quit
ftp -s:ftp2.txt
```

You will get a list of the records included date of file. Format of the records *may vary widely from system to system (RFC 959 - File Transfer Protocol).*
For example Windows FTP server may response:

```
12-04-11  08:00PM               209665 04a64ad1-33c6-48ec-9931-abcc6445c491
...
```

Linux may response:

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 owner    group             156 Jan 27  2010 warning.log
...
```

Comment: thanks, please could u show how to get last modified date of a remote file using dir

Comment: thank you very much!! one issue is that how to direct output of dir command to a variable, before Echo quit, so that the time obtained may be used further..

Comment: please may u help out for variable issue

Comment: dir command gets a list with end of line characters. Better redirect dir output to temporary file and read it line by line by "for /f" command.